# How to change ion-datetime time zone

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to change the time zone on my [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) from UTC to [Central Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone) (CST), but as of now, I haven't found any documentation to do so. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic states in their documentation to use [date-fns](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#advanced-date-constraints).